# How to loop through each column in Excel and apply column width based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am in need of excel vba code that will autofit all columns by default and then loop through each column width and if any width exceeds a particular value eg., 50, then restrict that particular column width to 30 and sets word wrap to true.

```
Public Function LastColumn(Optional wks As Worksheet) As Long
    If wks Is Nothing Then: Set wks = ActiveSheet
    LastColumn = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
End Function


Sub Macro1()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    LastCol = LastColumn(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"))
    For i = 1 To LastCol
        If Columns(i).ColumnWidth > 70 Then
            Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 70
            Columns(i).WrapText = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: record the macro and then edit it

Comment: If you still have issues after following @chancea's advice, show your code to improve your chances of a response.

Comment: the macro recorder will show you the objects and methods to use.  you have to put forth at least this much effort :)  after you have this information, it is just a matter of setting up the conditional logic per your requirements.

Comment: The code that he has posted is macro recorder code. The looping part cant be solved by macro recorder. Notice that he has the `AutoFit`, the `WrapText` and the `ColumnWidth`. I would say he has put in the minimum effort and the code is functional. All that is required is to use the UsedRange.Columns object (which you wont get from macro recorder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
Sub Autofit()

    Dim col As Range
    For Each col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns 'Only columns that actually have values
        col.Autofit
        If col.ColumnWidth > 50 Then 'Set your values here
            col.ColumnWidth = 30
            col.WrapText = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Note, this uses Excel widths, not Pixels